# What is the purpose of a fuse pin in a turbine engine?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine, turbine

what's the difference betweeen fuse pin and mounting bolts of an engine ? Are they the same ?
Any digram of a GE-90 engine showing those would be appreciated.

Comment: Fuse *pins* are basically metal cylinders which are designed to shear at a certain load. There is a fairly detailed description of the pins used on the Boeing 747 in [this FAA report](http://lessonslearned.faa.gov/ll_main.cfm?TabID=1&LLID=38&LLTypeID=2#null). Other Boeing airliners use similar pins.

Comment: Fuse pins were designed to let the pylons (and their engines) detach in case of wheel up landing, to prevent breaking the wings and igniting the fuel from the wing tanks. I'm not sure they are used today. There are *shear pins* at the engine mount level (the connection between the engine and the pylon), but not sure they play this role, it looks like they bear the lateral loads (thrust) in place of bolts. A shear pin is a pin, not a bolt. It cannot fix something onto something else, it does work in tension, only in shear.